# Title of a 1970s Sci-Fi tv show or tv movie featuring a character with a sort of psychic "tuning fork" that could turn thought into energy?

Tags: story-identification

**Plot Details/Summary**

Another one of my "long shot specials", I'm afraid.

The show was some sort of sci-fi adventure set on Earth or an Earth-like planet.  There is a mixed group of survivors/adventurers who are brought together somehow and all put into the situation they are in. I believe all of the characters are humans and from Earth.

The one thing I can really remember from the show is that one of the characters had a wand-like device that had a clear glass or plastic "tuning fork" on the end of it.  The character could focus his thoughts or will through the device, which would glow and do things like shatter glass, etc.

That's about all I can recall.  I don't know if it was only a tv pilot, or if it went to series.  It was definitely an American or Canadian produced show (i.e. it was not British) and I'm almost certain it was broadcast by one of the major tv networks.

**Timeframe**

Mid-to-late 1970s.  I think it was probably later in the 70s, though I'm not certain of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty sure this is [***The Fantastic Journey***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Journey) (1977)

> The series concerns a family and their associates who charter a boat out into the Caribbean for a scientific expedition. After an encounter in the area of the Bermuda Triangle with an unnatural luminous green cloud accompanied by the eerie disembodied sound of ship's bells, the group find themselves shipwrecked on a mysterious uncharted island from which they are unable to escape.

[image]

> Varian (Jared Martin): "A man from the 23rd century possessing awesome powers", Varian generally uses a kind of crystalline "tuning fork" device called the Sonic Energizer through which he focuses his thoughts into what is described as a sonic manipulation of matter.

[image][image]

Comment: That's unquestionably the show I was trying to remember.

Comment: Sonic Energiser?  Is he related to the Time Lords?